# JUnit 5: under what conditions is ExtensionContext.getTestMethod() not available?

Tags: java, junit5, junit5-extension-model

I'm working on a JUnit 5 extension where I am using the [ExtensionContext.getTestMethod()](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.1/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/ExtensionContext.html#getTestMethod--) to extract an annotation from test methods.

```java
Optional<Method> testMethod = context.getTestMethod();

if (testMethod.isPresent()) {
    MyAnnotation annotation = testMethod.get().getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);
    //snip...
}
```

According to the javadoc, the method returns

> "an Optional containing the method; never null but potentially empty"

I'm finding this a little confusing. In which situation would the test method be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say I have this extension:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Optional;

public class MyExtension implements BeforeAllCallback, BeforeEachCallback {
    @Override
    public void beforeAll(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
        Optional<Method> testMethod = context.getTestMethod();
    }
    @Override
    public void beforeEach(ExtensionContext context) {
        Optional<Method> testMethod = context.getTestMethod();
    }
}
```

and this test class:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;

@ExtendWith(MyExtension.class)
class MyTest {
    @Test
    void test1() {
    }
    @Test
    void test2() {
    }
}
```

When `MyExtension.beforeAll()` is executed: which test method should `context.getTestMethod()` return? `MyExtension.beforeAll()` is not test-specific, so within `beforeAll()` the call to `context.getTestMethod()` cannot return a test method!

The case is different within `MyExtension.beforeEach()`: this method is called before each specific test (i.e. once before `test1()` is executed and once before `test2()` is executed) and rightfully withn the `beforeEach()` method the call to `context.getTestMethod()` returns an optional with the corresponding method object.